# Checking for non terminating block statements in a file

Tags: visual-c++

I am working on a project that wants me to check for multi comments in a text file and also to see if it is a non terminating block statements. Pretty much I am using get char to check each character and compare it to the multi comment symbols and use peek to see if the next character matches the other symbols. The first part is working but to know when there is no terminating block statements is confusing please help.

```
if (c == '#' && inFile.peek() == '|') {
    char next = '\0';
    multipleComment += c;

    while (inFile.get(c)) {
        next = inFile.peek();
        multipleComment += c;

        if (c == '\n')
            lineNumber++;

        if (c == '|' && next == '#')
        {
            multipleComment += next;
            tokenTypes.push_back(multipleComment);
            values.push_back("COMMENT");
            lineNumbers.push_back(lineNumber);
            multipleComment.clear();
            break;
        }
        else {
            values.push_back("UNDEFINED");
            tokenTypes.push_back(text);
            lineNumbers.push_back(lineNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the syntax for a comment? It isn't clear from your code. Also, `c++` and `c++-cli` are quite different languages, so which are you actually using?

Comment: #| ...... |# it’s a multi comment.i am using c++

Comment: Maybe unrelated to the problem. Can one multiline comment contain another one inside it? Something like this: `#| ... #| .... |# ..... |#`

Comment: No but it can spams to other lines

Comment: @user8628552 Why can't you maintain a stack of positions where you found `#|`?

Comment: It makes sense, but I’m a lil bit confused with those

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: After you push to the stack each comment block when to check if  the other two ain’t there

Comment: Pop from the stack when `|#` comes. If you reach end of file, and still stack is not empty, you can then tell that there are some non-terminating comments.

Comment: What if there are more than one multi comments and some are non terminating c++

Comment: @user8628552 That's why I am asking you to store the position info in the stack

Comment: Position info meaning line number